# Issues with switching over from mains to generator

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator, neutral

This is my basic diagram:
[image: Schematic]

I'm facing an issue here - I have mains supply and generator supply and in order to incorporate a time delay I have have a UPS system in between.

The UPS is just powering the light loads - input to the UPS is from a switchover which switches between generator and mains.

The problem is that when switchover happens from mains to generator, my ELCB trips. Since the UPS has nothing to do with the ELCB the system works, but when switchover happens from generator to mains, we have to manually switch on the ELCB.

I doubt the low tripping current of 30mA is creating the issue, looking for suggestions …

Since my generator can't handle power loads, I can't completely transfer loads to generator.

What's your comments? Does increasing to a 100mA ELCB help?

Comment: I think the problem is that when your transfer switch creats an extra Neutral path (through the UPS) which bypasses your ELCB. An ELCB needs to see the same current flowing through both its Hot/Phase pole and its Neutral pole to remain happy - but with your 'bypass' of the neutral wire through the UPS you're splitting some of the Neutral current through there instead of through the ELCB's Neutral pole.

Comment: any solutions? b coz, since my load is of 2 kinds, there is only this way out..

Comment: If your transfer switch took its mains connection from the output/load side of your ELCB instead of directly from the incoming mains then you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I doubt the low tripping current of 30mA is creating the issue...Does increasing to a 100mA ELCB help?

If you doubt a less sensitive one would fix it, you're right. The UPS is powering loads, so the ELCB is seeing current on the neutral that it does not see on the line/live/phase, so it's doing exactly what it was made to do, and using a larger one won't help unless the UPS is powering a <99 ma load. Using a larger one *will* increase your hazard in the event of a fault.

I don't know what is *legally required* in your local area, but it *appears* that moving the neutral for the UPS supplied circuit to **only** connect to the UPS neutral (and NOT connecting the UPS neutral to the common neutral bar) would solve the problem, as the UPS neutral supply switches from generator to mains according to your diagram. Possibly that will require (for legal/safety reasons) another ELCB on the output of the UPS, since the UPS power is shown as being taken off before the ELCB.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems here.

As noted in Ecnerwal's answer, the UPS output should not be sharing a neutral bus with the utility.

But that's not all.

As wired, the UPS itself is consuming raw unprotected power from the utility, and the 6A "Light" breaker is serving no purpose, as the UPS is not capable of producing that much current.

Conceptually, the UPS and its branch circuits should be in a separate Consumer Unit fed by a *Protected* circuit from the one pictured here.

In practice you don't need another CU (or maybe legally you do, I don't know).   The 6A breaker should feed the transfer switch on the mains side.  The "Light" circuit Live and Neutral sides should both be connected directly to the UPS output terminals.

Assuming the UPS output is isolated, you then *do not* need another ELCB for the Light circuit because that would not work.  But if the UPS bonds the input and output neutrals then  you need to make sure the earthing system for the Light circuit and the main ELCB will all do their jobs both when on Mains and on Gen.  Hopefully the UPS documentation addresses this.  If  it does not, perhaps it was not intended to be integrated to household wiring?  Please make sure.

Also ... presumably the generator has its own breakers, but if not, you need ANOTHER breaker in the panel between the generator and the transfer switch input.

I'm interested in the make/model of the UPS.

Comment: ups is from APC SRC1KI-IN , the switch over circuit is programed and build by me with ESP8266 and a 10 A dpdt relay , this will send me a telegram msg whenever a switchover happens

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with your current wiring, your transfer switch creates an extra Neutral path (through the UPS) which bypasses your ELCB.
An ELCB needs to see the same current flowing through both its Hot/Phase pole and its Neutral pole to remain happy - but with your 'bypass' of the neutral wire through the UPS you're splitting some of the Neutral current through there instead of through the ELCB's Neutral pole.

I suggest that you change your wiring so that your transfer switch takes its mains connection from the output/load side of your ELCB instead of directly from the incoming mains - something like this:
[image]
Note that both wires from your incoming mains are *only* connected to the input/line side of your ELCB and nothing else.

Comment: this was tried, same result, when ever switchover happens from mains to generator, elcb trips

Comment: Then you have something else going on that's not shown in your diagram. Perhaps your generator bonds its Neutral to Ground or something like that...

Comment: What is the make and model of the UPS?